Redirect default language parameter to root with htaccess
I have been looking for a solution, but only found one similar case without an answer (unfortunately). Although the implementation is working, I am still missing one crucial aspect.
I am running a simple site (one php file) which loads the content based on the selected language and page. In order to have SEO friendly URLs, I am using the following .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

# 1. Redirect HTTP to HTTPS automatically (only if not in localhost)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# 2. Add a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ $1/

# 3. Default homepage
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=home

# 4. Language and page
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([^./]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2

The result:
index.php?lang=en&page=services -> /en/services/
index.php?lang=nl&page=diensten -> /nl/diensten/
...

However, I would like English without the language subdirectory, while other languages retain the language subdirectory.
index.php?lang=en&page=services -> /services/
index.php?lang=en&page=about -> /about/
...

I could use "RedirectMatch 301 /en/(.*) /$1", but that is not the proper way.
How would I accomplish what I need?

Have it like this:
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

# 1. Redirect HTTP to HTTPS automatically (only if not in localhost)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# 2. Add a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ $1/

# 3. Default homepage
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?lang=en&page=$1 [L,QSA]

# 4. default language to en
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/$ index.php?lang=en&page=$1 [L,QSA]

# 5. Language and page
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([^./]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]


That does the trick. The third rule plays the most important role here. I have tried to rewrite it with "page=home", but couldn't get it to work.

There is one small thing though. I had to add one more rule to make sure the homepages for the other languages are correctly rewritten:
RewriteRule ^(de|es|fr)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=home [L,QSA]

Yup that looks good
